# New div slide down on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the what i have created [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mWKkC/show/), my question is when the red,green,blue div is clicked, i need a new div sliding downwards and displaying its contents, how can i achieve it using Java script.

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mWKkC/)

HTML

```
<div class="profileimage">
</div>

<div class="about">
</div>

<div class="profile">
</div>

<div class="contact">
</div>

</div>
```

CSS :

```
body
{
margin:0;
padding0;
background:#262626;
}

.content
{
width: 860px;
height: 483px;
background-color: #fff;
position: absolute;
top:0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto; 
}

.profileimage
{
width:407px;
height:150px;
background:#ececec;
float:left;
border-right:1px solid #fff;
}

.about
{
width:150px;
height:150px;
background:#F26B6B;
float:left;
border-right:1px solid #fff;
}


.profile
{
width:150px;
height:150px;
background:#A8D324;
float:left;
border-right:1px solid #fff;
}

.contact
{
width:150px;
height:150px;
background:#50C0E9;
float:left;

}
```

Comment: As i am new to JS, I'm just wondering how can i do it? I have seen many examples but none worked for me.

Comment: It would be great to see some JS implemented on your fiddle, just to get started.

Comment: I'm still working on that.

Comment: You're using jQuery as well, correct?

Comment: At this moment i am googling on JS/jQuery.

Comment: Read my answer, I've tried to make it as explainable as possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**this might be easier**

jquery

```
$('.about, .profile, .contact').on('click', function() {
    $(this).children('.inner').slideToggle().parent().siblings().children('.inner:visible').slideUp();
});
```

html

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="profileimage"></div>
    <div class="about">
        <div class="inner">some stuff1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="profile">
        <div class="inner">some stuff2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="contact">
        <div class="inner">some stuff3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
html, body{margin:0;padding:0}
.content, .inner{width:860px;position:absolute}
.content {
    height: 483px;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
.profileimage,.about,.profile,.contact {
    height:150px;
    float:left;
    border-right:1px solid #FFFFFF
}
.about,.profile,.contact{width:150px}
.profileimage{width:405px}

/* bg */
body{background-color:#262626}
.content{background-color: #FFFFFF}
.profileimage{background-color:#ececec}
.about{background-color:#F26B6B}
.profile{background-color:#A8D324}
.contact{background-color:#50C0E9}

/* added*/
.inner{top:150px;left:0;height:333px;display:none;background-color:#000000;color:#FFFFFF}
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/gTN8W/

Comment: This so so super! Thank you FiLeVeR10! :)

Comment: Anytime, glad it helped!

Comment: If i need to add this will this api work? <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: it should. the fiddle is using 10.1, so 10.2 should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle I've made for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/BHMUq/

I simply added the following jQuery code:

```
$(".about").click(function() {
    if ($("#contents").is(":visible")) {
    $("#contents").slideUp();
    } else {
        $("#contents").slideDown();
    }
});
```

I also added a div containing content with the id `contents` and styled it with this:

`#contents {display:none; height:40px;clear:both}`

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Waclock/mWKkC/12/)'s a working fiddle with what you have requested.

Basically the JS you need is something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.contact,.profileimage,.about').click(function(){
    $('#hiddenDiv').slideDown();
    });
});
```

Basically what the javascript is saying is the following:

1) When the document is ready (when the website has finished loading) do the following:

2) For the classes "contact","profileimage","about", if any of them are clicked perform the following actions:

3) Select the element with id hiddenDiv `$('#hiddenDiv')`  and slide it down -> `$('#hiddenDiv).slideDown()`

You can give hiddenDiv any properties you want, keeping in mind that in the css you must add the following line to `hiddenDiv` -> `display:none`